# Use Variable in eventcreate batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, event-viewer

I need to tweak an eventcreate statement in an existing, but antique, batch file, to include a variable in the event log.

I've tried multiple ways but can't get it to work.

The statement currently looks something like this:

```
eventcreate /SO "batch file name" /Id 999 /D "specific event" /T INFORMATION /L Application
```

I need to include the value of a variable in the description like this:

```
eventcreate /SO "batch file name" /Id 999 /D "variable value is %%test%%" /T INFORMATION /L Application
```

I tried placing that variable outside the quotes, but the event log entry shows the variable name, but does not replace it with the actual value of the variable.

Anyone know if this can be done?

Comment: If you want the variable value, instead of the variable itself, could you please explain why you are using `%%test%%` instead of `%test%`?

Comment: That was just one of the many things I was trying to get the value of the variable to show up.  Using %test% didn't work either.

Comment: Well you haven't explained where, when or how you defined a variable named `test`. Unless you do so, I really do not know how you expect us to assist you without guessing. You have submitted only a one line command, with nothing whatsoever to aid us to put it into context within a batch file. So understanding that we can only assist you properly when we can reproduce your environment and issue, please [edit] your question to clarify such things.

Answer (score 0):

`/D    description      Specifies the description text for the new event.` (c) `eventcreate /?`

it isn't working that you think (variable escape once) use `%test%` without `%%test%%`

"self-updated description"? I don't understand you. please update this question / left a comment / try `%var%`

maybay `%test%` isn't contained some value? (`isn't variable`)

check `%ProgramFiles%` without `%%test%%` it's work

Comment: The first thing I tried was %test% and that didn't work.  Using the double %% was one of the other many things I tried, and yes, the variable %test% does in fact have a value

Comment: try

echo eventcreate /SO "batch file name" /Id 999 /D "variable value is %test%" /T INFORMATION /L Application

maybay you use variable with "insecure" value (quotes, special symbols)?